# How can fluorite structure exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, bravais-lattices

From the information from Google the radius of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ cation is $100 \,\pu{pm}$ and of $\ce{F-}$ anion is $132\, \pu{pm}$, so essentially $\ce{F-}$ ion should form the Bravais lattice (FCC/CCP) as it is larger in size and $\ce{Ca^2+}$ should go to the tetrahedral voids but in reality it is just opposite.

How can smaller sized calcium cation form the Bravais lattice?

(The data has been taken form first results form Google search)

Please do correct me if I am conceptually wrong somewhere.

Comment: Smaller ion does not always go to interstices, as smaller ion sometimes tend to increase stability of lattice, also in case of CaF2, it's not uncommon to get complex isometric forms. Crystal twinning is rather much more common...

Comment: The "lattice" atoms do not have to be the largest.  They only have to be large enough to fit the "interstitial" atoms around them, and when the coordination number is less than 12 (in this case it's 8) this can be done with the "lattice" atoms slightly smaller.